# How to create a PDF file that will have initial view=Fit

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, itext, adobe-reader

I am trying to use the iText Stamper to change a PDF file so that it will always open with full page display.  I tried,

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(new PdfReader(src), new FileOutputStream(dest));
PdfWriter writer = stamper.getWriter();
PdfAction action = PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(1, new PdfDestination(PdfDestination.FIT), writer);
writer.setAdditionalAction(PdfWriter.DOCUMENT_OPEN, action);
```

but DOCUMENT_OPEN is not defined.  How can I do this?  Should I be using instead stamper.addJavascript? but what JS code will setup the initial view?

I could use setPageAction(PAGE_OPEN, action, 1) and that works, but I think it might be annoying to the user if every time they look at page 1, the view changes.

BTW, initially I tried to use the PDF Open Parameters, but they are very unreliable. I displayed the pdf using

```
<embed src='myfile.pdf#view=Fit'>
```

and Adobe Reader often ignores the view for no apparent reason.  That is why I am trying to set the initial view within the PDF itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
writer.setOpenAction(action);
```

Also see the [documentation for setOpenAction](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#setOpenAction%28com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAction%29).